# Entidade não pode ser referenciado por várias instâncias

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Estou tentando salvar os dados nesse método aqui...

```
public ActionResult AtualizaInicioAtividade(Atividade atividadePre, Atividade atividadePrincipal)
    {
        try
        {
            using (CPMDatabaseEntities db = new CPMDatabaseEntities())
            {
                atividadePre.Ativo = atividadePre.Ativo;
                atividadePre.CodigoMilestone = atividadePre.CodigoMilestone;
                atividadePre.Descricao = atividadePre.Descricao;
                atividadePre.Inicio = atividadePrincipal.TerminoCedo.AddDays(1);
                atividadePre.InicioCedo = atividadePre.Inicio;
                atividadePre.TerminoCedo = atividadePre.TerminoCedo.AddDays(atividadePre.TempoRevisado);

                Tarde(atividadePre);


                db.Entry(atividadePre).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Dashboard");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
// metodo ainda em construcao
 public ActionResult Tarde(Atividade atividade)
    {
        try
        {
            using (CPMDatabaseEntities db = new CPMDatabaseEntities())
            {
                int QtdDependencia = db.Dependencia.Where(a => a.AtividadePrincipal == atividade.Codigo).Count();

                if (QtdDependencia == 0)
                {
                    atividade.TerminoTarde = atividade.InicioCedo.AddDays(atividade.TempoRevisado);
                    atividade.InicioTarde = atividade.TerminoTarde.AddDays(atividade.TempoRevisado * -1);
                }

                if (QtdDependencia == 1)
                {
                    atividade.InicioTarde = Convert.ToDateTime("10/10/2015");
                    atividade.TerminoTarde = Convert.ToDateTime("10/10/2015"); 
                }

                return View(atividade);
            }             
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }

    }
```

Porém aparece esse erro aqui:

***An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in ISystemCritical.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.***

Comment: O que faz o método `Tarde`?

Comment: atualizei a pergunta.

Comment: já tentou chamar `db.Entry(atividade).State = EntityState.Detached;` antes do seu return no método Tarde?

Comment: Não funcionou...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este erro está acontecendo pois você está utilizando dois DbContext para manipular uma mesma entidade.
Voce até podia utilizar o método Detach em versões mais antigas do Entity Framework e acredito que o método do @Bruno funcionaria, mas saiba que este método foi removido por um motivo:
Diferente dos métodos Attach, Add e Remove, o Deatach não operava nos relacionamentos da entidade, então você teria que se preocupar em chamar o Detach para cada uma das entidades relacionadas (entidades filhas) manualmente.

Mesmo que você insista em contornar o problema, você está deixando de aproveitar o que o Entity Framework traz de melhor.

A idéia geral, e que faz o Entity Framework tão poderoso, é que ele "observa" todas as entidades que você busca do Banco, e que você adiciona no contexto.
Assim, com um único `SaveChanges()`, ele, salva todas as entidades de uma única vez (de forma atômica), executando inserts, updates ou deletes, conforme a necessidade.

Isso quer dizer que o melhor a se fazer no seu caso é reescrever seu fluxo, evitando que dois contextos tenham que ser criados:

```
 public ActionResult AtualizaInicioAtividade(Atividade atividadePre, Atividade atividadePrincipal)
        {
            try
            {
                using (CPMDatabaseEntities db = new CPMDatabaseEntities())
                {
                    atividadePre.Ativo = atividadePre.Ativo;
                    atividadePre.CodigoMilestone = atividadePre.CodigoMilestone;
                    atividadePre.Descricao = atividadePre.Descricao;
                    atividadePre.Inicio = atividadePrincipal.TerminoCedo.AddDays(1);
                    atividadePre.InicioCedo = atividadePre.Inicio;
                    atividadePre.TerminoCedo = atividadePre.TerminoCedo.AddDays(atividadePre.TempoRevisado);

                    ConfiguraTarde(db, atividadePre);


                    db.Entry(atividadePre).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    db.SaveChanges();

                    return RedirectToAction("Dashboard");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }

private void ConfiguraTarde(CPMDatabaseEntities db , Atividade atividade){
                    int QtdDependencia = db.Dependencia.Where(a => a.AtividadePrincipal == atividade.Codigo).Count();

                    if (QtdDependencia == 0)
                    {
                        atividade.TerminoTarde = atividade.InicioCedo.AddDays(atividade.TempoRevisado);
                        atividade.InicioTarde = atividade.TerminoTarde.AddDays(atividade.TempoRevisado * -1);
                    }

                    if (QtdDependencia == 1)
                    {
                        atividade.InicioTarde = Convert.ToDateTime("10/10/2015");
                        atividade.TerminoTarde = Convert.ToDateTime("10/10/2015"); 
                    }

}

    // metodo ainda em construcao
     public ActionResult Tarde(Atividade atividade)
        {
            try
            {
                using (CPMDatabaseEntities db = new CPMDatabaseEntities())
                {
                   ConfiguraTarde(db , atividade);

                    return View(atividade);
                }             
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }

        }
```

Isto deve resolver no momento, mas lhe aconselho a ler [este ótimo tutorial](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) do msdn que mostra, por exemplo, que você não precisa usar o `Using(DbContext)` em cada action.